# UIkit Dynamics in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to convert some objective c code to swift and struggling to achieve results.

```
animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
_gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[square]];
```

at to moment I have got

```
animator.referenceView = self.view
```

Doesn't work though. Can someone guide me in the right direction. Thanks in advance

Full Code

```
let square = UIView()

    square.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
    square.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

  self.view.addSubview(square)

    var animator = UIDynamicAnimator()
    var gravity = UIGravityBehavior()



    animator.referenceView = self.view

    animator.addBehavior(gravity)
```

Comment: what's the problem? do you have compiler error or something?

Comment: @BryanChen Cannot assign 'referenceView' to 'animator'

Comment: post more your swift code... one line is not enough. and full error message

Comment: briefly, `var animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

holex was on to it, but the key is that you have to store a reference to the animator, here's a working example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var animator:UIDynamicAnimator?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let square = UIView()

        square.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)
        square.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        self.view.addSubview(square)

        self.animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView:self.view)
        var gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [square])

        animator!.addBehavior(gravity)

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Holex had the right idea, but you put it all together. :)

Comment: I also face that problem. Thanks for an answer such a helpful. And for that 1 upvote. But I can't understand why it so? Can you please tell me reason for that?